# Получить уникальные значение в таблице MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Есть таблица с полями `имя, фамилия, телефон.`
Как получить уникальное значение по всем трем полям.
Делаю по телефону уникальность, работает:

```
SELECT DISTINCT phone
 FROM promocodes
```

Но нужно что бы по всем трем было

```
SELECT DISTINCT surname, name, phone
        FROM promocodes
```

Так не работает.

Comment: В этой теме предложено несколько вариантов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188027/mysql-select-distinct-multiple-columns

Comment: вот что-то вы либо умалчиваете, либо под уникальностью трех полей что-то другое подразумеваете, уточните задачу, покажите пример результата где у вас дубли

Comment: Сделайте три отдельных запроса, каждый по одному из полей.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так

```
SELECT surname, name, phone
    FROM promocodes
    GROUP BY surname, name, phone
```

Comment: @pggood Выдает ошибку You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Where status=1 ORDER BY RAND()' at line 4

Comment: В моем примере нет такого кода: Where status=1 ORDER BY RAND(). Покажите весь ваш запрос, GROUP BY должен идти после WHERE

Comment: не смысла в этом никакого. distinct для этих целей предназначен

Comment: @teran Аргументируй пожалуйста. в аналогичной теме ответ c группировкой имеет больше всего голосов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188027/mysql-select-distinct-multiple-columns

Comment: работает некорректно, вывед два одинаковых значения

Comment: Вероятно, отличия все таки есть, возможно пробелы лишние, или регистр букв, или буквы е/ё. Если покажете данные и запрос, смогу подсказать точнее

Comment: замечательно что там больше всего голосов, однако он не принят, и решает вообще другую задачу нежели автор просил. Причем эта задача не такая как тут.

Comment: @teran В чем различия по вашему? И я что-то не вижу вашего решения с использованием DISTINCT

Comment: у автора в вопросе уже есть дистинкт. зачем это постить ответом?

Comment: @teran автор хочет получить уникальные комбинации значений из трех полей, а вы в комментариях уговариваете его, что ему нужно что-то другое, может вы сами что-то не понимаете?

Comment: уникальные комбинации получает инструкция distinct. Если она не работает, значит автор имеет в виду что-то другое. Давайте бесполезный спор прекратим и дождемся пояснений к вопросу. Ваш текущий ответ даст ровно тот же самый результат что и использование distinct но более сложным путем

Comment: *автор хочет получить уникальные комбинации значений из трех полей* Нет. Будь так - второй запрос в вопросе решает эту задачу. Автор хочет для каждого поля отдельно получить уникальные значения. Просто он не может об этом нормально сказать.